# Solving tic-tac-toe through brute force

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

I have been struggling with this problem for a while. I need to solve tic tac toe through brute force - that is, by having the computer "learn" by playing itself a few million times.

Right now, the "setup" works - I'll briefly describe it. My computer plays itself by generating random moves, until one side or the other has won. It then stores the list that represents the game, and associates the list with a 1, 0, or -1 for a win, draw, or loss.

The algorithm I'm currently using is a simple one; I find what move on the board is associated with the most wins and least losses, out of all the games that can result from the current board, and then I move there.

This works for nearly ever case; all except the important ones: forks.

In a situation like this:

```
o - -       o - x     o - x

- x -   >   - x -  >  - x -

- - o       - - o     o - o
```

where the computer has the next move, the computer invariably goes in a corner, and later gets forked.

Is there a way to solve tic tac toe through "brute force" only (without using min/max, heuristics, hard coding for forks, etc.)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement machine learning on tic-tac-toe? After a while, when the computer learns the optimal moves, it will not ever be able to win against itself: If both players make optimal moves, then the outcome will ALWAYS be a tie. In my opinion, you should apply machine learning to another game such as chess or checkers.

Answer (score 2):

A few million times may be excessive.  I think there are only about 362,880 possible "games" (Statistics: first player has 9 options, next player has 8 remaining, then 7, etc.. so 9! = 362,880).

I would recommend weighing your move selection based not just on eventual win/loss, but on Number of Moves required to win.  Fewer moves = better decision.

Also, once you build a "complete" map, you can map certain moves in certain situations as "death" moves, leading inevitably to loss.  A well designed weighing metric would see that there is *no* route to win, and never select that move (which would include forks).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is a few million times excessive if the games are randomly generated? I've attempted weighing played games by game length, but I'm always not sure where to go from there. My gut feeling - not sure if thats worth trusting - also tells me that if games are randomly generated, the "shorter games" will occur more often - and thus will have more "weight" than longer games that are more unlikely scenarios.

Comment: Well, if you're really doing "Brute force" then you can manually generate each of the 362,880 boards and build a complete database of every possible situation.  Then it's just a database searching problem.

Comment: Sorry- didn't quite add this in before I hit enter - part of the reason why I *think* there is an advantage to randomly generating games is that games of a shorter length will be more likely to occur than games of a longer length. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Again, there is a finite space of possible games.. If you build the database of all possible, many of them will end before the full 9-moves, so the real space will be even smaller than the 362,880 .